# Is it possible to redirect an elastic beanstalk doman name to an EC2 doman?

Tags: amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk

I had a site running on elastic beanstalk and sent out the url for demonstration purposes. That site has now moved out of elastic beanstalk to a plain Amazon EC2 instance. I would like to keep the same url so that anyone I previously sent the link to will still be able to access the site. Is it possible to automatically redirect the elastic beanstalk domain to my EC2 instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you give your customers the actual EB domain? If so, why on earth did you do that? Those are not meant for general consumption. Rather, you are supposed to configure a `CNAME` that points to the EB endpoint they provide.

Anyway, if you've given out that address, the only way to retain that as a functioning endpoint is to keep that EB stack running. You can change it to something very minimal - just perform a simple HTTP redirect to your "real" server, but nonetheless, you'll need to keep it active.